# How to get Log in Android?

Tags: android, logging, ibeacon-android

I am trying to develop a Beacon Application in Android. In that i want to get that how many times a beacon is getting scanned in one minute. I know this is possible through log. So how to get it?
I am new to this and need very much so please help if anybody has answer!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Log.i("Beacon", beacon.toString());` something like this u have to code.

Comment: @AnandSingh I want to know with time i.e in which time each beacon got scanned . Also can i get these in csv or textfile?? Thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Tip: A good convention is to declare a TAG constant in your class:

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
```

Don't forget that when you make a call like

```
Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);

int ASSERT  Priority constant for the println method.
int DEBUG   Priority constant for the println method; use Log.d.
int ERROR   Priority constant for the println method; use Log.e.
int INFO    Priority constant for the println method; use Log.i.
int VERBOSE Priority constant for the println method; use Log.v.
int WARN    Priority constant for the println method; use Log.w.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the log through the following code:

```
public class LogTest extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

      StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        log.append(line);
      }
      TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      tv.setText(log.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

The above code reads the log and displays it in a textview.

You should define:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

permission in your manifest.

To copy the log directly to a file,use the following method:

```
public static void copyLogcatToFile(Context context) {    
    String fileName = "log_cat"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".txt";
    File outputFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(),fileName);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f "+outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: I have tried exacty as you have told but it is not showing the time and also can i get it in csv format instead of txt!  Thanks

Comment: try changing the .txt extension to csv

Comment: yh tried but i am getting everything in one line only and also the extra stuff is also there so it looks very complex!